# Add twitter bootstrap icon in button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a bottom in twitter bootstrap but want to add a icon in the bottom. Is that possible ?

This is the button:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">{{ HTML::linkRoute('change_log', 'Endringslogg', array(), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}</div>
```

Icon I want to add:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a macro to handle this

```
HTML::macro('button', function($route, $title, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())
{
    $icon = array_get($attributes, 'icon');

    $iconTag = $icon ? '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'.$icon.'"></span> ' : '';

    if ($icon) unset($attributes['icon']);

    return HTML::linkRoute($route, $iconTag.$title, $parameters, $attributes);
});
```

Then in your blade template do something like:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">{{ HTML::button('change_log', 'Endringslogg', [], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'icon' => 'user']) }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a helper which is not using HTML::linkRoute as this method encodes html entites so you would end up with this:

```
<a href="http://your.url">&lt;span class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-user&quot;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;</a>
```

---

And here's the helper

```
if ( ! function_exists('icon_link_to_route')) {
    /**
     * Create link to named route with glyphicon icon.
     * 
     * @param  string $icon
     * @param  string $route
     * @param  string $title
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return string
     */
    function icon_link_to_route($icon, $route, $title = null, $parameters = array(), $attributes = array())
    {
        $url = route($route, $parameters);

        $title = (is_null($title)) ? $url : e($title);

        $attributes = HTML::attributes($attributes);

        $title .= '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-'.e($icon).'"></span>';

        return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.$attributes.'>'.$title.'</a>';
    }
}
```