# Edit icon displayed as text

Tags: laravel

I am creating an app in laravel. I have crated a function "helper.php"

```
public static function fa_link_to_action($action, $text, $icon = '', $params = array(), 

    $attrs = array()) {     
                if ($icon) {
                    $text = '<i class="fa fa-' . $icon . '"></i> ' . $text;
                }
                return link_to_action($action, $text, $params, $attrs);        

        }
```

And i am calling this function in my view

```
{{ Helpers\Helper::fa_link_to_action('CarController@edit','Edit','plus',null,$v->id)}}
```

The problem is that it shows this : `<i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Edit` 
not the icon

Comment: That's a Font-Awesome class. Do you have Font-Awesome's CSS files loading properly in your layout? It's not going to just magically work without that step.

Comment: Your icon string is processed with `htmlentities` by `link_to_action` helper, so you need to make some changes to your helper function like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23322989/add-twitter-bootstrap-icon-in-button/23323937#23323937

Comment: @deczo it is saying calss Helper\HTML not found

Comment: It's `\HTML` if you have your helper in the namespace. Also check the @Razor's answer as it seems a quicker way to achieve the same result.

Comment: $attributes = \HTML::attributes($attributes); ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return \HTML::decode(link_to_action($action, $text, $params, $attrs));
```